# Why doesn't event name shown in sepolia.etherscan?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a smart contract deployed to Sepolia network. One of the method emits 3 events. Please take a look at https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x31f77360db4cd51f5db7954d143d0fb514b96d71fa409c17b3412f78c11ee6a3#eventlog as an example.

There are 3 logs and 2 of them are `Transfer` but the last one doesn't have any name as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

The first two `Transfer` events are emitted from `@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol` code while the last one was emitted by this contract, the code is:

```
  event SectorCreated(address owner, int x, int y, uint256 width, uint256 height, uint256 price);

...

  emit SectorCreated(msg.sender, x, y, width, height, price);
```

I am not sure what the `SectorCreated` event is now shown. What is the different between the `Transfer` and `SectorCreated` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etherscan uses combination of its own database and ABI of the event emitting contract to decode the signature hash (`topics[0]`, e.g. value `0xbfa038b0...`) into human-readable format (e.g. `SectorCreated`).

The `Transfer` event is likely in their own database (because it's standardized ERC-20 event), but `SectorCreated` is not.

In this case, the contract that emitted the event is [0xc9986cf63eee2d04117300e1963083ccbb2ea301](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xc9986cf63eee2d04117300e1963083ccbb2ea301). Its source code / ABI is not verified on Etherscan, so the site doesn't know how to decode events that the contract emits.

Solution is simple - verify the contract source code on Etherscan. I'm just not sure if it applies retroactively to already sent transactions or only new ones after the verification.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How do I `verify the contract source code on Etherscan`? Is there a special way during deployment?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao The contract is deployed on chain in the form of the bytecode. Etherscan (and other blockchain explorers) doesn't have access to the source code (which is not on chain) unless you feed the source code to the site. You can do it manually using a form (https://etherscan.io/verifyContract) or programmatically with their API (tutorial: https://docs.etherscan.io/contract-verification/verifying-contracts-programmatically). Many blockchain development frameworks also have plugins where you only specify your Etherscan API key, run a command, and they leverage the API verification for you.